Polars complex function via the numba JIT (circumventing the return entity limit of 1)
In a Polars DataFrame, I have 3 columns (A, B, D) storing value of type double.
For n rows, and a starting value of some double number, the calculation is performed as shown below:
value of column A = value of column A * initial value
value of column B = value of column B * initial value
value of column D = value of column A + value of column B
initial value = value of column D

Unfortunately, complex custom functions of this nature can only be satisfactorily performed via numba gufuncs as of Polars (v0.20.26).
My Issue is, I am only able to return 1 element from the gufunc and still have it be compatible with Polars (Polars does not support multiple returns as of yet). So in the end, even though I get my final results for column D, the values for column A & B are not retained.
One way to circumvent this would be to simply perform the same computations two more times solving for the desired column's values - but this is rather an inefficient way to go about this. I also tried to hoodwink polars and numba by making the value of column D an array of [column A, column B, column D] but numba does not allow this with Polars columns as a message is returned informing of the data being elided (which I've noticed, is usually a signal of numba's incompatibility with data). I've also tried turning the column information into a comma-combined string to no avail - we just can't pass complex data like that to numba - not as far as I know.
I wrote a custom C function, but for some very odd reason, Python is so abysmally slow in calling a C function form it's native API that it takes about a 100 times longer than the polars complex function as described above. I can only guess this is due to taking time wrapping everything into PyObjects - even though I got the same slow result using numpy arrays... There is simply no way for me to take it to a lower level with the provided Python C API as the calls are abnormally slow for some reason - regardless of how many parameters I pass or how complex my data seems to be.
I am at my wits end at the moment. The only options I can think of at the moment are:

Convert this portion into a function consisting & dealing only with numpy arrays on the numba JIT.
Store the dataframe column data in something like pickle, SQLite & get to multiple sets of these with a final light-year long call signal to C just before terminating the Python routine.

I wanted to post here first to see if there was an easier way out of this pickle (no pun intended).

Could you provide an example dataframe along with the expected output? It‘d make answering much easier.

You say that you're only able to return 1 value from your gufunc but without any example or code, it's just a guess as to why you're having that issue.

In general, polars can handle multiple returns. They just need to be packed into a polars series (i.e. use a Struct series). From the documentation:

The output of this custom function must be a Series (or a NumPy array,
in which case it will be automatically converted into a Series).

As a simple example, consider the following.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [1, 1, 1],
    "C": [0, 1, 0],
})

df_new = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("A").map_batches(
        lambda x: pl.Series({"D": x[i], "E": 2 * x[i]} for i in range(len(x)))
    ).alias("result")
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ result    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ struct[2] │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ {1,2}     │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ {2,4}     │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ {3,6}     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘

The "result" column can be unnested into the struct fields "D" and "E" using pl.DataFrame.unnest.
df_new.unnest("result")

shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   ┆ E   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 3   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

A common pattern here is to have a pure numpy function that is numba jit-compatible and a simpler wrapper handling the conversion (polars to numpy and  numpy to polars). In your concrete case this could look as follows.
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, b, initial_value=1.0):
    a_new = np.empty_like(a)
    b_new = np.empty_like(b)
    d_new = np.empty_like(a)

    carry = initial_value
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a_new[i] = a[i] * carry
        b_new[i] = b[i] * carry
        d_new[i] = carry = a_new[i] * b_new[i]

    return a_new, b_new, d_new

def unpack(a_new, b_new, d_new):
    df = pl.DataFrame({
        "A_new": a_new,
        "B_new": b_new,
        "D_new": d_new,
    })
    return pl.Series(df.to_dicts())

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.struct("A", "B").map_batches(
            lambda x: unpack(
                *f(
                    x.struct.field("A").to_numpy(), 
                    x.struct.field("B").to_numpy(),
                )
            )
        ).alias("result")
    )
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ result    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ struct[3] │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ {1,1,1}   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ {2,1,2}   │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ {6,2,12}  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘

Note. With some more thought, the conversion of the numpy arrays to the polars Struct series (in unpack) can likely be made a bit more elegantly.

thank you so much for the detailed answer despite my now noticed vagueness with the question. i found out that the only thing making the entire C function call slow was the .to_numpy() function. the .to_list() was oddly instantaneous. strange. so i did move the code to C, but the process you describe is worth implementing. because right now, the C code is writing out results to a struct and Python is reading it back for further processing which is just a terrible thing to do... but i had to test for code accuracy as well.

i had previously learned the gufunc technique from answers to this question i posted the other day. then polars raised exceptions telling me it had not implemented more than 1 return at a time for such types of functions. i looked up and down but never managed to find what you showed here. this could possibly be a gamechanger. it's a tough job to write documentation for something as polars, but the examples for map_batches were the most basic ones.

if you don't mind, please link some resources to learn information of polars techniques in detail. thanks again!

@mindoverflow Glad it helped. I approach polars mostly with a learning-by-doing approach. I think the overall API is not that large and one can quickly become familiar with the common functions & objects. Reading some answers to (seemingly unrelated) questions on stackoverflow also helps me a lot to discover new techniques.

i'm not very well-versed in rust, so it is very difficult for me to experiment with polars at the moment - i always find myself wondering if some technique i used might have slowed down the entire pipeline... for example, the numba functions that are not gufuncs take about 0.1 second to just load up - even with cache=True. the c version returns the entire process within 0.004 seconds - but moving to C for a process that is itself small but might be called thousands of times seems like a huge pipe clog - especially with the struct dumping...

python has somehow turned into a terrible middle man for me at the moment... it's usually so well taken care of - but the whole rust compatibility is much less mature than the c interop support i guess.

@mindoverflow Usually, >95% of the use-cases can be covered by native python polars without ever touching the rust interface. If you have specific functionality that cannot be covered by the native expression API, you could try asking on SO. Possibly, there are simple and idiomatic solutions :)
